# Joining a list of values with table rows in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

Suppose I have a list of values, such as `1, 2, 3, 4, 5` and a table where some of those values exist in some column. Here is an example:

```
id  name
 1  Alice
 3  Cindy
 5  Elmore
 6  Felix
```

I want to create a `SELECT` statement that will include all of the values from my list as well as the information from those rows that match the values, i.e., perform a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` between my list and the table, so the result would be like follows:

```
id  name
 1  Alice
 2  (null)
 3  Cindy
 4  (null)
 5  Elmore
```

How do I do that without creating a temp table or using multiple `UNION` operators?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

If in Microsoft SQL Server 2008 or later, then you can use [Table Value Constructor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776382.aspx)

```
 Select v.valueId, m.name 
 From (values (1), (2), (3), (4), (5)) v(valueId)
     left Join otherTable m
        on m.id = v.valueId
```

Postgres also has this construction [VALUES Lists](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/queries-values.html):

```
SELECT * FROM (VALUES (1, 'one'), (2, 'two'), (3, 'three')) AS t (num,letter)
```

Also note the possible [Common Table Expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/queries-with.html) syntax which can be handy to make joins:

```
WITH my_values(num, str) AS (
    VALUES (1, 'one'), (2, 'two'), (3, 'three')
)
SELECT num, txt FROM my_values
```

With Oracle it's possible, though heavier [From ASK TOM](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=value-list-items-that-are-not-in-the-table):

```
with id_list as (
  select 10 id from dual union all
  select 20 id from dual union all
  select 25 id from dual union all
  select 70 id from dual union all
  select 90 id from dual
)
  select * from id_list;
```

Comment: is there a way to generate series of int dynamically rather than hardcode them ?

Comment: Works in SQL Server, but I'm still looking for a more useful command format, as those parenthesis around the individual values are just...too much.

Comment: @user3079364, What do you mean dynamically? You mean in T-SQL? If so, then sure, create an empty table variable, then populate it with T-SQL Insert statements generated using whatever logic you wish.

Comment: @JakeJ, The parentheses, (or some other token), are necessary as a separator between each row of data. Within each parentheses would be a comma delimited set of values for that single row of data... as in `(values (1, 16, 'Dave'), (2, 22, 'Mary'), (3, 8, 'joey'), (4, 55, 'Dad'), (5, 46, 'Mom')) v(PersonId, Age, Name).` Without the parentheses, some other token would be necessary to separate the rows.

Comment: Is there any equivalent in SQLite, or does that DB's serverless nature prevent that?

Comment: Works with Postgres too.. Thanks a lot

Comment: @JakeJ regarding "parenthesis around the individual values are just...too much" SQL Server Management Studio supports advanced editing features like [link](https://www.meziantou.net/visual-studio-tips-and-tricks-multi-line-and-multi-cursor-editing.htm)

Answer (score 4):

the following solution for oracle is adopted from [this source](http://rebustechnologies.com/convert-a-csv-string-into-rows-using-oraclesql/). the basic idea is to exploit oracle's hierarchical queries. you have to specify a maximum length of the list (100 in the sample query below).

```
   select d.lstid
        , t.name
     from (
               select substr(
                           csv
                         , instr(csv,',',1,lev) + 1
                         , instr(csv,',',1,lev+1 )-instr(csv,',',1,lev)-1
                      )  lstid
                 from (select ','||'1,2,3,4,5'||',' csv from dual)
                    , (select level lev from dual connect by level <= 100)
                where lev <= length(csv)-length(replace(csv,','))-1         
          ) d
left join test  t on ( d.lstid = t.id )
        ;
```

check out [this sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/21891/1) to see it work.

Answer (score 2):

Bit late on this, but for Oracle you could do something like this to get a table of values:

```
SELECT rownum + 5 /*start*/ - 1 as myval
FROM dual
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 100 /*end*/ - 5 /*start*/ + 1
```

... And then join that to your table:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(SELECT rownum + 1 /*start*/ - 1 myval
FROM dual
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 5 /*end*/ - 1 /*start*/ + 1) mypseudotable
left outer join myothertable
    on mypseudotable.myval = myothertable.correspondingval
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming myTable is the name of your table, following code should work.

```
;with x as 
(
  select top (select max(id) from [myTable]) number from [master]..spt_values
),
y as
(select row_number() over (order by x.number) as id
from x)
select y.id,  t.name
from y left join myTable as t
on y.id = t.id;
```

**Caution: This is SQL Server implementation.**

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/57297/1)

Comment: I am not sure I understand. How and where does the list of values (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) come into play?

Comment: Well this can handle anything from 1 to whatever your highest id may be (1,2,3,4,5,....,n).

Comment: Sorry for misleading you. I introduced the `id` column just for illustration purposes. The list of values does not have to represent a list of IDs, rownums or even sequential numbers. It can consist of arbitrary strings or any other distinct values.

Answer (score 1):

For getting sequential numbers as required for part of output (This method eliminates values to type for n numbers):

```
declare @site as int
set @site = 1
while @site<=200
begin
insert into ##table
values (@site)

set @site=@site+1
end
```

Final output[post above step]:

```
select * from ##table
select v.id,m.name from  ##table  as v
left outer join [source_table] m
 on m.id=v.id
```

Answer (score -1):

Suppose your table that has values `1,2,3,4,5` is named `list_of_values`, and suppose the table that contain some values but has the name column as `some_values`, you can do:

```
SELECT B.id,A.name
FROM [list_of_values] AS B
LEFT JOIN [some_values] AS A
ON B.ID = A.ID
```

Comment: The problem is that the list of values is not in any table. I guess my original question boils down to: how do I convert a list of arbitrary values into a subquery that can be used in a `join`?